# Mouse theme doesn't  work all the time

Tags: 11.04, themes

The mouse theme shows up in the web browser and software center, as well as the update manger.  However, it goes to defaults on the desktop.  Can it be fixed?

I am using the azenis mouse theme, with Natty Beta 1.  got swich to natty beta 2 and still the problem

Comment: I using azenis mouse theme, os natty beta 1

Comment: what is the output of `ls ~/.icons`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/69105/my-default-mouse-cursor-doesnt-change-no-matter-which-theme-i-use

Answer (score 2):

This is because Unity is compiz based, to fix this:

`sudo gedit /usr/share/icons/default/index.theme`
 or `gksu gedit /usr/share/icons/default/index.theme`
and change the cursor name.
(source: forums)

Comment: For a more detailed guide, see http://www.webupd8.org/2010/08/how-to-change-mouse-cursor-theme-in.html

Comment: Only the `gksu` version of the command should be used, to avoid creating problems with gedit's configuration when it is run later. See [the community documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Graphical_sudo) for details.

Answer (score 1):

Try "galternatives" from the software centre, this allows the x-server cursor to be set, thus the cursor is set before you log in and should hold

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 10.04, as well as 11.10, supporting Unity, A BUG mixes cursor themes ?! 
Nevertheless doing :

`sudo gedit /usr/share/icons/default/index.theme`

as suggested - does not help, because in `../icons/default/` directory only shortcut to your theme exists and Unity mix it with the default DMZ-White (black). 
I am using oxygen theme, after installing it with package manager - type 'oxygen cursor' I did the following :

I have tried to copy under 'gksudo nautilus' all content of `../icons/oxy-white/*` to the 
`../icons/default/` directory - and GREAT !!! ... after the restart it works PERFECTLY !!!

P.S. I am using LinuxMint 11 Katya / Ubuntu 11.10

Comment: that's why I have made it by DEFAULT, because it is making me nervous to be changed all time long ?!