# Wallpaper is broken and mouse pointer is inconsistant

Tags: 11.04, unity, compiz, desktop-background, cursor

I've got Natty running on a desktop for my parents to use. Everything's going fairly smoothly, but...

- the wallpaper is broken. it's just a light grey, and when I go to change it, I get weird black and white polygons behind windows for a little while.
- the pointer is being silly, for lack of a better word. I've selected the large "redglass" pointer theme because my Dad has low vision, but the pointer is inconsistent. On the desktop, launcher, panel etc, it's the default white one, but in Firefox and LibreOffice, it’s the large red theme.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Any updates on this?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure u have logged out and then log back in, that should fix the pointer theme not changing, if it still persists install lxappearance, `sudo apt-get install lxappearance` and change the mouse cursor theme from there.

Comment: LxAppearance will fix it, but it causes theming problems because it sets a global setting for your account and the only way to change it is to delete a hidden file in ~/.icons and ~/.themes.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your mouse cursor is a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/702211) in compiz, and you can mark it as affecting you, as well as request that it be taken with priority (I'm sure they will listen if you mention that it is an accessibility issue).

The wallpaper problem, I'm not too sure about what could be causing that. Does nautilus work in general?

Comment: Thanks, I'm about to mark the bug as affecting me. Good idea :)

Nautilus seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 0):

In case you tried to play with transparency and used gnome-color-chooser and murrine when you were on ubuntu 10.10, try again to deactivate/reactivate murrine in gnome-color-chooser -> rendering engine (I put murrine for both global and dashboard).

Comment: Ah, I did fiddle with transparency when it was still on Maverick. 

I deactivated and then reactivated murrine, but it just caused the old black and white polygons problem. Once the desktop calmed down, it reverted to the light grey wallpaper.

Answer (score 0):

The mouse pointer problem has been addressed on another AskUbuntu question right [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/34800/18510).