# My default mouse cursor doesn't change, no matter which theme I use

Tags: settings, cursor

If I open gnome-tweak-tool, go to the Theme section and choose the DMZ-Black cursor theme, my default cursor stays exactly the same. However, the *other* cursor images (like when I move a window or hover over a link) are the correct ones from the DMZ-Black theme. The same happens if I choose the Adwaita theme, for example.

Does anyone know why this is? How can I completely change my cursor theme so that the default cursor is also changed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Multi-user 14.04

If you have only one user on your system, it will be ok to change default curser theme, whether by copying DMZ-Black contents onto DMZ-White, or changing default index.theme content, or even using command `sudo update-alternatives --config x-cursor-theme`.

But on a multi-user system, you need to personalize for yourself alone without affecting other users. Well, it's not so hard. You just need to make a "default" curser theme under your home.

Let's change the cursor theme in steps:

**Via Terminal**

1. `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface cursor-theme "DMZ-Black"` – simply replace "DMZ-Black" with your desired theme
2. `mkdir ~/.icons/default`
3. `gedit ~/.icons/default/index.theme`
4. copy the following lines in the text file and save it:

   ```
   [Icon Theme]
   Inherits=DMZ-Black
   ```

   – again replace "DMZ-Black" with your desired theme.

**Via GUI**

1. Install [Dconf Editor](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/dconf-editor) or [Unity Tweal Tool](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/unity-tweak-tool) to be able to change the cursor theme;
2. On **Dconf Editor**, search for "cursor-theme", double click it and change the value to "DMZ-Black" or your desired theme.

   [image: Change mouse cursor theme via Dconf Editor]

   Alternatively on **Unity Tweak Tool** under Apearance, go to Cursors and select "DMZ-Black" or your desired theme.

   [image: Change mouse cursor theme via Unity Tweak Tool]
3. Open Files (Nautilus) and go to `~/.icons` (make one if there isn't any);
4. Make a new folder, name it `default` and open it;
5. Make an empty document and name it `index.theme`;
6. Open the file, paste the following lines and save it:

   ```
   [Icon Theme]
   Inherits=DMZ-Black
   ```

   You can replace "DMZ-Black" with your desired theme.

   [image: Default cursor theme]

**This works also on Synaptic Package Manager and Nautilus with root privileges.**

Source: [Raschix's comment](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/08/how-to-change-mouse-cursor-theme-in.html#comment-65625438) on a post from webupd8.org 4 years ago!

Comment: The terminal method worked for me in Ubuntu Studio 15.10 when the selected black pointer from the mouse preferences would switch between black and white depending on the window beneath. I had to create the directory ".icons" first however with: mkdir ~/.icons

Answer (score 9):

In a terminal enter this:

```
gksu gedit /usr/share/icons/default/index.theme
```

Then change DMZ-White with exact name of the theme you want use, in your case DMZ-Black. Then it will show the correct theme.

Comment: Thank you! That solved my problem. I learnt I can also change that by using sudo update-alternatives --config x-cursor-theme.