# Ubuntu tweak tool - Mouse cursor would not change theme

Tags: themes, cursor, tweak

I tried to change the cursor theme from DMZ-White to DMZ-Black for my laptops. But it does not work for one of my laptop.

For that laptop, it does not work no matter I change the cursor theme in 
- Ubuntu tweak tool,
- or changing it in gksu gedit /usr/share/icons/default/index.theme, 
- or changing it in sudo update-alternatives --config x-cursor-theme

What else can be done to change it? Thanks in advance!

==edit==
sorry turns out that my mouse cursor is partially changed.... in the main content of firefox browser, the cursor is changed to black, however if the cursor is on the launcher / File/Edit/View bar, it is still white.

How come???

Comment: Which Desktop environment you are using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/69105/my-default-mouse-cursor-doesnt-change-no-matter-which-theme-i-use

Answer (score 11):

That is a known issue. 
To change your cursor globally follow below instruction.

Open terminal and paste `gksu nautilus` hit `enter` then insert your password hit `enter`.

You will be now viewing `nautilus` as root. now go to `file system` on left panel.

Navigate to `/usr/share/icons/default` and open `index.theme` with your favorite text editor and change `DMZ-White` to `DMZ-Black`.

Or you can apply this change easily by executing the below command

`sudo sed -ri 's/DMZ-White/DMZ-Black/g' /usr/share/icons/default/index.theme`

And it's done! Either Reboot your computer or run the command to see the changes

```
compiz --replace
```

Comment: Editing the file alone doesn't help on my computer.  Does some process need to be restarted or receive a signal?  (I haven't tried restarting my session).

Comment: my laptop's cursor changed to black cursor today after restart. Strange thing is that I did restart the laptop too yesterday. Anyways thanks man!

Comment: sorry turns out that my mouse cursor is only partially changed.... please refer to the question edited part

Comment: I have already followed the instructions to edit the index.theme. however it doesn't work for me :(

Comment: Ubuntu 15.04 Followed instructions (only difference: used `#` to comment the original line). `compiz --replace` resulted in some process which froze and forced me to reboot. After that I got the desired black pointer - though only in the system and most programs. Firefox and Thunderbird still have the white version like before (both were opened while doing `compiz --replace`). So the pointer switches from black to white and back depending which program is beneath it.

Comment: Ok somehow managed to fix it with http://askubuntu.com/a/538863/455821 the terminal method there and redoing `compiz --replace` with no programs opened...

Answer (score 9):

you can use
`sudo update-alternatives --config x-cursor-theme`

Then choose any theme you like..

to apply either `restart` or `compiz --replace`

Answer (score -2):

compiz --replace

(Enter above command at your own risk) - Just reset my Ubuntu 14.04 because this command broke my compiz. simply try log off or restart the computer. (also submitted as an edit)