# Cursor theme changes to default after re-login

Tags: themes, icons, 15.10, cursor, cursor-theme

I'm running Ubuntu 15.10, I changed my cursor theme to `dmz-black` then restarted. It worked, but when I just logout and login cursor theme has changed to default (`dmz-white`) yet `dmz-black` theme is working only on Google Chrome.

So I again restarted then again the correct theme appeared then I again logout and login then again cursor theme changed to default (correct theme only working on Chrome).

**I changed the theme using many ways**

1. Through Unity Tweak Tool
2. By editing `/usr/share/icons/default/index.theme`
3. By running `sudo update-alternatives --config x-cursor-theme`
4. Via Dconf-Editor
5. By creating `.icons/default/index.theme` and pasting

   ```
   [Icon Theme]
   Inherits=DMZ-Black into index.theme
   ```

But none of these methods solved my problem.

Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem using Ubuntu Studio. Xfce has a built-in setting for mouse pointers. The standard black pointer works after reboots, but changes at some point I can't define. Then, the pointer will switch between white/black depending on the focused window (e.g. white on panel, black on browser, etc.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu tweak tool - Mouse cursor would not change theme](http://askubuntu.com/questions/295101/ubuntu-tweak-tool-mouse-cursor-would-not-change-theme)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

You must have a hidden directory and a file named `index.theme` in your user home directory like `~/.icons/default/index.theme`

open it with your text editor and replace Inherits with :

```
[Icon Theme]
Name=Default
Comment=Default Cursor Theme
Inherits=dmz-black
```

Then logout and login

If your mouse theme changes per application then

open ccsm > general options and enter your mouse theme name in `Default Icon`

There is a tool named **lxappearance** in repo, you can use it to customize your theme with it.

Comment: Thanks, But It seems not working..thanks in advance for mentioning the app lxappearance

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a live USB? Live USBs have the OS on them but reset after restart. Try setting up a persistence file when using a USB so you can save the changes

Comment: i just installed ubuntu using a usb (pen-drive) thats it. i didnt get what u asked

Comment: He was asking if you were running Ubuntu from a USB drive or have it fully installed on your hard drive. I can confirm that this happens on a full installation.

Comment: @Prototype700 thanks..thats right! happens on a full installation. I just re-installed xcursor-themes and dmz-cursor-theme using Synaptic Manager many times..but no answer